# Is it possible to install/embed jquery to your web Browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, block

Is it possible to install/embed jQuery in the browser?
The area, where I live, will block anything related to google. For example：

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
```

I can visit stackoverflow.com but with a js error if I don't use VPN.
I don't mean my own site. When I visit some site, I know the error is JQuery is missing. If I have the JQuery.js. I will not need the VPN.

[image]

Comment: You can download jQuery from other sources than Google CDN, for example directly from jQuery website.

Comment: China ? Just download the JS and host it on your website.

Comment: jQuery official website ( code.jquery.com ) sometimes get blocked as well.

Comment: Download and Host Jquery on your machine..
Link to download: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js

Comment: What about Microsoft CDN or even CloudFlare? https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/

Comment: Very related: [Use of ajax.googleapis.com not China-friendly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258288/use-of-ajax-googleapis-com-not-china-friendly)

Comment: I voted to move this question to Super User, since it seems to be about using websites that use googleapis.com, rather than developing a site of your own.

Answer (score 3):

Very related: [Use of ajax.googleapis.com not China-friendly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258288/use-of-ajax-googleapis-com-not-china-friendly). 
The solution given there is to use Hola, a browser plugin that lets you browse through a VPN, although I'm afraid that also may not work.

I think the best solution is to host the files on a local webserver or on your own remove server, and change the hosts file in Windows to make googleapis.com redirect to that location.